# Radio buttons dont work / change when clicked

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button

Seems like I am stuck with weird problem....appears to be simple ( and very trivial for some) but simply does not work.

I have a simple div with some radio boxes which simply do not change state after clicking...

```
    <div id="payments_tab" class="tab-pane fade" data-toggle="tab" role="tabpanel" >
    <div class="container" >
    <div class="form-group field-space">
        <div class="col-md-2"  >
        <label for=""> Price per day (default) </label>
        <input type=text size=3 name="prop_price" id="prop_price" value =" <?php echo $home["price"];?>"  
            onkeyup="calculateCost();" class="form-control input-md"   />

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
             <label for="prop_adv_payment_share">Advance Payment expected (%)  </label>
             <select  type="choice" id="prop_adv_payment_share" name="prop_adv_payment_share"  onchange="calculateCost();"  class="form-control input-md" > 
                <option id=1 value="0.1" >10%</option>
                <option id=2 value="0.15">15%</option>
                <option id=3 value="0.2">20%</option>
                <option id=4 value="0.25">25%</option>
                <option id=5 value="0.30">30%</option>
                <option id=6 value="0.33">33%</option>
                <option id=7 value="0.4">40%</option>
                <option id=8 value="0.45">45%</option>

            </select>
        </div>

    </div>  
    <div class="form-group field-space">
        <div class="col-md-10 field-space"  >
        <label   > Balance amount to be paid as cash on arrival at the property ? </label><br/>
            <input type="radio"     name="balance_payment" value="1" <?php  if ( $home["cashOnArrival"] ) echo "checked"; ?> 
             id="balance_payment_yes" ><label for="balance_payment_yes" >Yes</label>

            <input type="radio"     name="balance_payment" value="0" <?php  if ( !$home["cashOnArrival"] ) echo "checked"; ?>
             id="balance_payment_no"    ><label for="balance_payment_no" > No</label>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

So far I checked following :
1)  Ensured name tag is same for all radio buttons 
2)  included lable with for tag that corresponds to related radio button
3) each radio has an id

what am I missing .....?

Comment: Verified your code without `payments_tab` div and removed php code (I am not a php developer) and see no issues with your HTML I can toggle between Yes/No radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer.
The issue is with  data-toggle="tab" setting on first DIV.
After I remove this tag, things work fine.

Hope this helps someone having similar issue/problem.

Still, not sure why this Bootstrap attribute should mess with behavior of core html element......would be great if someone can throw some light on this....